# sum of multiples of 10 array

Tags: arrays, input, sum

I'm just having a problem with my program to return sum that only had multiples of 10 with numbers that were input by the user. I have most of the code written, but it might be my if statement where i'm having problems at (if(i%10==0)).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question2 {
public static void main(String[]args)
{
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
int [] value;
int x;
int sum=0;
System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to store?");
x= input.nextInt();
value= new int [x];

while(x<=0)
{
    System.out.print("Error please enter a value greater than 0");
    x= input.nextInt();

}

for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Input number");
    value[i]= input.nextInt();  
}

for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    if(i%10==0)
    {
        sum=sum+value[i];

    }
}
System.out.println("The sum of multiples of 10 is:" + sum);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the value is a multiple of 10, you would do `value[i]%10 == 0` instead of `i%10 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The final for loop of your code is not using the variable 'i' properly. You are not interested in the value of 'i', you are interested in the ith number that was input by the user, stored in the 'value' array. Therefore you should use 'i' as an index to the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    if(value[i] % 10 == 0){
        sum += value[i];
    }
}
```